# Does specific function exist?

Tags: analysis

Check if exists function $f(x,y):R^2->R$ such that f(x,y) has directional derivatives in point (0,0) in each direction and (0,0) is point of discontinuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put f equal to zero everywhere but on the curve  $y=x^2$, where it is 1. Try to fill in the details.

Comment: if f(0,0) = 1 there wouldn't be any directional derivative. Must we add that f(0,0) = 0?

Comment: This may be a detail :-)